# Check for specific image in background

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using Supersized to randomly display 3 SVG background images on refresh. I am trying to use jQuery to check which SVG is displayed so I can then change other css accordingly. The code I'm starting with is:

```
if ($('#supersized').css('background-image') == "public/images/red-bg.svg") {
    alert('There is a background image');
}
```

I am not sure how exactly to check for which image and the above isn't working. Help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to include the full `background-image` syntax in the comparison: `== "url(public/images/red-bg.svg")`. That said, it would be better if you used a class to assign the background image as then you could just check for that class being present on the element.

Answer (score 1):

Its very likely that `background-image`'s value wont be exactly `public/images/red-bg.svg`. So you should check if it contains that URL using the method `indexOf`. Also, the first condition in the `if` is to avoid errors in case that `background-image` is not set (it's value would be `undefined`).

```
var bgImg = $('#supersized').css('background-image');
if (bgImg && bgImg.indexOf("public/images/red-bg.svg") > -1) {
  alert('There is a background image');
}
```

The method `indexOf` returns the position of a substring within a string. For example for the string `"HELLO"` and subtring `"H"` it would return `0` and for the substring `"ELL"` would return `1`. It returns `-1` when the substring is not found.

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: Thank you for this Diego, I do really want to understand the code above. What does the > -1 do? Thank you

Comment: Youre welcome. I've just updated my answer giving you more information.

Answer (score 1):

You could store your string matches into a `bgCSS` object and have all your additional CSS style references cleanly ordered and in place:

```
var $supersized = $('#supersized');

var bgCSS = {
  // BG MATCH   : {ADDITIONAL STYLES}
  "red-bg.svg"  : {color:"white", borderColor:"#a01"},
  "blue-bg.svg" : {color:"yellow", borderColor:"#0f0"}
};

if ($supersized.css('background-image').match("red-bg.svg")) { // if has that BG...
    $supersized.css( bgCSS["red-bg.svg"] );  // ...apply our additional styles
}
```

http://jsbin.com/hutepa/1/edit?html,css,js,output